# vim replace all tags in a cscope/ctags search (files not in buffer)

Tags: vim, replace, ctags, cscope, exuberant-ctags

Is there a way to replace all the tags from a cscope search in vim?

I installed cscope per [their tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) in Ubuntu 16.04 along with ctags.

For example, I execute:

```
:cs f s MyTag

Cscope tag: MyTag
   #   line  filename / context / line
   1    122  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             MyTag& ReturnMyTag();
   2    233  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             MyTag my_var;
   3    256  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             typedef struct MyTag
```

None of the files are loaded in buffers.
I would like to be able to reaplace all these instances with a new tag:

```
:s/MyTag/MyNewTag/g
```

so that I get this:

```
:cs f s MyNewTag

Cscope tag: MyNewTag
   #   line  filename / context / line
   1    122  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             MyNewTag& ReturnMyTag();
   2    233  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             MyNewTag my_var;
   3    256  f.h <<GLOBAL>>
             typedef struct MyNewTag
```

Comment: have a look at `:h cdo` should be what you are searching if I am not mistaken (Not 100% sure where cscope displays the results, but should be the quickfix list)

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion sent me through the right path. The solution is a bit more involved thou. Will post soon.

Comment: Do you have a solution now? may I ask you to post it?